# How to save canvas as an image in Spring Rest webservice

Tags: rest, canvas, spring-ws

How to save canvas as an image in Spring Rest webservice, canvas contains graph based on user inputs. I need to auto save graph as an image (I get image data using canvas.toDataUrl()) to server. Server has spring REST web services.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this~

```
// jsp
function saveCanvasImage(){
    var imageData = myCanvas.toDataUrl();

    $.ajax({
        url:'/controller/path/saveCanvasImage',
        data:{imageBase64: imageData},
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 10000,
        async: false,
        error: function(){
            console.log("WOOPS");
        },
        success: function(res){
            if(res.ret==0){
                console.log("SUCCESS");
            }else{
                console.log("FAIL : " + res.msg);
            }
        }
    });
}


// java(controller)
@RequestMapping(value = "/controller/path/saveCanvasImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody public Map<String,Object> saveCanvasImage(
        @RequestParam(value="imageBase64", defaultValue="")String imageBase64) {
    Map<String,Object> res = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    File imageFile = new File("/home/data/canvasImage.png");
    try{
        byte[] decodedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(imageBase64.replaceAll("data:image/.+;base64,", ""));
        BufferedImage bfi = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes));
        ImageIO.write(bfi , "png", imageFile);
        bfi.flush();
        res.put("ret", 0);
    }catch(Exception e){
        res.put("ret", -1);
        res.put("msg", "Cannot process due to the image processing error.");
        return res;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Good luck